# JavaScript equivalent to CSS * (everything) selector

Tags: javascript, css

Is there an equivalent of the CSS `*` selector in JavaScript?
How can I achieve the same effect in JS that the following CSS snippet does?

```
* {
    background-color:"#000000";
}
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("*");`? Besides, your CSS declaration is not valid; It should be `background-color: #000000`.

Comment: If you're in jQuery, `$("*")`.

Comment: `var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");`

Comment: you don't: use css for styling many elements at once to avoid inline styles

Comment: can you explain a bit more, what are you tring to do here, selecting * in js? are you tring to set a same style via js?

Comment: @buddhi I program a small webpage which should have a functionality of swichting between different color patterns. As the background colour of all elements should be the same everytime I'd like to use `*` so I do not have to loop throu all elements.

Comment: you are aware of the fact that backgrounds, colors, and everything else, can be inherited, right? (that's the "cascading" part in "cascading style sheets", or CSS) Just use several different named classes for your different themes, and switch only the master elements that control the inheritance

Comment: what are the elements you use, div, input etc... ?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you for that comment, I was not aware of that since I tried to solve 'everything' by JS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using plain JavaScript, you can use the `querySelectorAll()` method:

```
document.querySelectorAll("*");
```

This will return a `NodeList` containing all the elements selected. To style them as the CSS does:

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("*");
for(var i=0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i].style.backgroundColor = "#000";
}
```

You can of course use any other styles. To be technically correct, you would have to wrap `querySelectorAll()` in `Array.prototype.slice.call()` to convert it to a fully-formed array instead of a `NodeList`, but for this purpose this is unnecessary.

However, the `querySelectorAll()` method is relatively new, so to ensure total support you might want to use this:

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("*");  // gets all elements
for(var i=0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i].style.backgroundColor = "#000";
}
```

That does exactly the same thing but with a different method. `querySelectorAll()` should **technically** be used as this is its purpose but either works.

N.B.: If you're using jQuery it's even easier:

```
$("*").css("background","#000000");
```

Lastly, if it's just CSS control you want when selecting everything, you can use a CSS setup as described [here](http://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets) by David Walsh. There is an example implementation of this in [this script](http://jenkinsstuff.bl.ee/cdn/libs/utils/utils.js).

Comment: In your first example `nodes` is a `NodeList` - but why can you still access it by `[]` like arrays?

Comment: Because a `NodeList`, like a jQuery selection, is array-like. While it doesn't have all the associated functions of the Array prototype, it can still be accessed with the `[]` syntax because it contains indexed values. Try it: type `querySelectorAll("*")` into your browser console and inspect the returned `NodeList`. You will be able to use `NodeList[index]` sytax on it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var allNodes = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
var node;
for(var i=0;i<allNodes.length;i++){
  node = allNodes.get(i);
  node.style.backgroundColor = '#000000';
}
```

Note that although this would work... I'm not sure it is what you would really want. (e.g. this will attempt to style elements that may not accept it (e.g. like a `<style>` or `<script>` tag)

Comment: I'd rather add a class name to the elements.

Comment: you should cache the allNodes.length if you're looping every tag on a dynamic collection. ("*") can be pretty slow.

Answer (score 2):

@scunlinf's answer is a partial answer, but your question is odd: why would you do CSS in JS instead? You actually **still** want CSS:

```
var all = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("*"));
all.forEach(function(e) {
  e.classList.add("blackly");
});
```

and a CSS class:

```
.blackly { background: black!important; }
```

Because you don't want hardcoded CSS values in your JS, you want to keep those properly controllable, switchable, etc. etc. etc so you use CSS classes for the styling, and at most you toggle classes on the JavaScript side of things.

(If the `Array.prototype...` part is new to you, `document.querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList, which is like an array but also very much not. By running it through the `slice` function, it generates a proper array with all the array functions like `.every`, `.forEach` etc)

Comment: But it would be possible to do it like so: `document.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(function(e){e.style.backgroundColor="#000000";});`? (I appreciate your effort to teach me how it should really be done=)

Comment: if you mean pseudocode: yes. If you mean that code: no, because document.querySelectorAll is not an array, and style controlling uses `e.style.propertyName`, not `e.propertyName`. And that said: of course, but don't do that because no matter how small the page is, hardcoding values is setting yourself up for bugs and problems as little as minutes later.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the goal is interactively changing the colour pattern of a html/js document.

Comment: right, so generate CSS classes and then switch between those in your JS. Don't use `.style....` properties

Answer (score 1):

You could simply insert a `<style>` tag in the HTML.

```
var css = '* { background: red; }',
styletag = document.createElement('style');

styletag.type = 'text/css';
if (styletag.styleSheet){
  styletag.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
  styletag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}

document.body.appendChild(styletag);
```

### JS Fiddle Demo

Comment: Is this really 'the way to go'? It seems to work, but I have the notion that it is the 'wrong' method of doing so?

Comment: @flawr That is not "the way to go", as you can see there are plenty of working solutions. This one just avoids JS loops, it is probably a faster alternative. It's up to you to decide which one works best for you.